# Custom response in mongo eve based on actual response

Tags: eve

By default, While a fetching a resource, it returns a Object with key `_items`.

```
{
    "_items": [
        {
            "_id": "5d0b787a10414b47f8e8c858",
            "username": "A",
            "message": "TEST",
            "_updated": "Thu, 20 Jun 2019 12:13:43 GMT",
            "_created": "Thu, 20 Jun 2019 12:13:43 GMT",
            "_etag": "1fad0ab63ebe77731bf623800b8367ac6b94e8a8"
        }
    ]
}
```

but I would like to get only the array of items as response.

```
[
        {
            "_id": "5d0b787a10414b47f8e8c858",
            "username": "A",
            "message": "TEST",
            "_updated": "Thu, 20 Jun 2019 12:13:43 GMT",
            "_created": "Thu, 20 Jun 2019 12:13:43 GMT",
            "_etag": "1fad0ab63ebe77731bf623800b8367ac6b94e8a8"
        }
]
```

I tried using `on_fetched_resource`. It can modify the response Object. But not able to assign an array to response

Answer (score 0):

I think it can't be done, as the response is to be a dictionary which contains keys that might appear (pagination data, HATOEAS links, and actual documents).

As per Nicola larocci answers, it is currently not possible, however if you are using ajax or someother thing to fetch the response, you can chop off _item or use some other technique to do so.